# Sequelize conflict between Sync and Migrations

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

When I invoke sequelize.sync() sequelize create database in mysql name like Article,Book.
But I invoke sequelize db:migrate sequelize create database in mysql name like Articles,Books.
How to avoid this problem? 
[this is my mysql screensshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9pfU.jpg)

Comment: please share your schema for this two tables .

Comment: @VyasArpit  I found the problem,remove option 'freezeTableName: true'.Thank you.

Comment: Okay great!!  :)